# How to check if a list is part of another list in Python

Tags: python, list, set

I have the following lists:

```
first=['a','b','c']  
second=['a','a']  
third=['a','b']
```

Is there way to compare second to first so I get FALSE,and TRUE for comparing third to first? I tried using sets but `set(second).issubset(first)` returns True, which is not what I need.

Comment: Does the order matter?  Does it have to match from the beginning of the list exactly?

Comment: What if `first = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']` ?

Comment: @JonClements I should have clarified yes the order doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first=['a','b','c']  
second=['a','a']  
third=['a','b']

def sub_set(lst1, lst2):  
    tmp = lst2[:] 
    for i in lst1:
        if i in tmp:
            tmp.remove(i)
        else:
            return False
    return True

print sub_set(second, first)
print sub_set(third, first)
```

output

```
False
True
```

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly for my case as I needed matches even when the order is different. Clever solution, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if the order matters and the elements need to be sequential you could convert the list to a string (with `join`) and use this:

```
first=['a','b','c']
second=['a','a']
third=['a','b']

def is_sublist(sublist, reflist):
    return ''.join(sublist) in ''.join(reflist)

print(is_sublist(sublist=second, reflist=first))
print(is_sublist(sublist=third, reflist=first))
```

Comment: Just to note that if the list contains non-string elements or string elements of more than one character this approach becomes impractical...

Comment: I forgot to clarify the order doesnt matter. I would like a list like `fourth=['a','c']` to be able to match True with first list. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a comparison using slicing:

```
>>> first = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> second = ['a', 'a']
>>> third = ['a', 'b']
>>> second == first[:len(second)]
False
>>> third == first[:len(third)]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter, you can use a count dictionary:

```
diffs = {a : second.count(a) - first.count(a) for a in second}
diffs_list = list(diffs1.values())

is_subset = len(diffs_list) == diffs_list.count(0)
```

That returns `True` for `third`, and `False` for `second`.

This simply counts the occurrence of each element of the subset in the superset, computes the difference of each count, then verifies that all differences are `0`.